# Creating a 1000 x 2 matrix where one column is constant and the other alternating

Tags: matlab

I would like to create a 1000 x 2 matrix where the first column consists of all 1's while the second column alternates between 2,0,2,0... . So, the matrix will consist of 1000 1's in the first column and alternating with 500 2's and 500 0's in the second column. How, using MATLAB, can I create this matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build the first column, use the function `ones`. To build the second column, first define the piece `[2 0]'`, a two-element column vector, and use `repmat` to repeat it 500 times along the first dimension. Finally, use the concatenation operators `[]` to put the two columns together.

```
m = [ones(1000, 1), repmat([2 0]', 500, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
m = repmat([1 2; 1 0], 500, 1);
```

We create a base matrix: `A = [1 2; 1 0];`, then stack this 500 times to create the matrix you desire.

If you don't like the `repmat` method, another way would be to create a matrix of ones which is 1000 x 2 long, then take the second column and add this with an alternating `[1 -1]` sequence that spans 1000 rows:

```
m = ones(1000,2);
m(:,2) = m(:,2) + (-1).^(0:999).';
```

We can even go mathematical and make the first column all ones, and the second column be:

```
y = 1 + cos(pi*x)
```

`x` would be an integer starting from `0` up to `N-1` where `N` is the total number of rows you want.  When `x` is even, `cos(pi*x) = 1` and when `x` is odd, `cos(pi*x) = -1`.  By adding this with 1, depending on what value `x` is, we will alternate between `2` and `0`:

```
m = [ones(1000,1) 1 + cos(pi*(0:999)).'];
```

Comment: Your first answer was already most elegant, but your variations make it really nice. :)

Comment: How about `bsxfun(@power, [0 -1], (0 : 999)') + 1`? ;-)

Comment: Or `1 - cumprod(ones(1000, 1) * [0 -1])`? – Sorry, I'll stop now...  ;-)